# R programming: regexpr next occurence

Tags: regex, r

I have the following code and results:

```
> x <- c("ABCDE CDEFG FGHIJ")
> x
[1] "ABCDE CDEFG FGHIJ"
> regexpr("D", x)
[1] 4
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
```

regexpr only returns the first occurrence of "D", how can I get it to return all occurrences of "D"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close -- just a couple of line down from `regexpr` in the help file...

```
gregexpr("D", x)
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 8
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 1 1
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use strsplit like this :

```
which(unlist(strsplit(x,split=""))=="D")
[1] 4 8
```

This way you can also have exact match for D.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there will be a pure  `regex` approach. However `stringr::str_locate_all` will suffice

```
library(stringr)

unique(unlist(str_locate_all(x, 'D')))

## [1] 4  8
```